# How can I keep the trailing zereos with .3g?

Tags: python, numbers, decimal, significant-digits

I have the following value: 6.095651174e-09 and I am printing it like this:

```
print(f' the result is: {forces[index]: .3g} N')
```

Here the output is *6.1e-09* but I want to keep the zero after it was rounded from *6.09* to *6.1*.
My desired output would be: *6.10*

A normal float works with this. But with g it does not work anymore. I want to keep the E at the end and therefore I want to stay with g (and not f).

Is it possible to have *6.10e-09* printed out here? I only found things for float and those solutions did not work with my case.

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the issue with the `e` type:

```
i = 6.0956e-9
print(f'result: {i: .2e} N')
```

Output:

```
result:  6.10e-09 N
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks! Is there a good site to understand g,e,d and so one more in contexts like this?

Comment: You can read [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/), especially the [Standard Format Specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#standard-format-specifiers) section. To be honest I have no clue why `g` and `e` behave differently in your case, it should be the same for numbers that require an exponent…